# How to change only the column variable without changing the paths and formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I only replace the Column variable and not the formula and the path?

Eg.
Average(E10:E20) I want to change to Average(X10:X20)
but if I do replace (E -> X) then I get
AvXragX(X10:X20)

Also changes the path if I am using external reference I don't want to change them manually...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing this is formula only and not VBA?  I'll remove the VBA tag....

Answer (score 0):

So do a replace of "(E" to "(X" and ":E" to ":X"

That will then avoid the E in average.

Comment: but what if it is a specific cell? like for example, I have column E externally referenced to another workbook with formula https://"some file path that contains multiple e" with formula =E# of the other workbook. and I want to change the formula so that now it is all referenced to column F of the other work book. in that case I cant use the ":E" method since it is of the form E#

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case-sensitive replacement. Only uppercase "E" in the range will be replaced, and not lowercase "e" in "Average".

If you need to address more precisely your range (if it ever contains uppercase "A" for example), follow @Solar Mike answer.